# Unknown nested variable unable to determine existence of nested sub.... things, always NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay, so I have the following variable in Ruby:

```
GroupOfPeople
```

I am NOT able to do...

```
GroupOfPeople.persons |do|
```

It returns a NoMethodError.

However, I CAN do a

```
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
 # Do things
 }
```

However, each person, whatever their unknown variable type may be, may (or may not) have traits. For example, with all of them I can call...

```
 A_proper_hash = {}
 A_proper_list = []
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
   p n.id
   A_proper_hash[:id] = n.id
   A_proper_list << A_proper_hash
 }
```

And this works fine. And if there's a chance some of the persons have a nil value, I can do...

```
 A_proper_hash = {}
 A_proper_list = []
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
   n.middle_name.nil? ? A__proper_hash[:middle_name] = nil : A__proper_hash[:middle_name] = n.middle_name
   A_proper_list << A_proper_hash
 }
```

However, some of the persons won't even have the variable, let alone assigned as nil. And that crashes the program. I have tried multiple ways to get around it.

```
 A_proper_hash = {}
 A_proper_list = []
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
   if n.key(:pet_name)
     n.pet_name.nil? ? A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = nil : A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = n.pet_name
   end
   A_proper_list << A_proper_hash
 }
```

The Above returns "NoMethodError"

This also returns "NoMethodError"....

```
 A_proper_hash = {}
 A_proper_list = []
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
   @n.respond_to?(:pet_name).should n.pet_name.nil? ? A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = nil : A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = n.pet_name
   A_proper_list << A_proper_hash
 }
```

And this also returns NoMethodError...

```
 A_proper_hash = {}
 A_proper_list = []
 Persons = GroupOfPeople.persons
 Persons.each {|n|
   if(respond_to? n.pet_name)
     n.pet_name.nil? ? A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = nil : A__proper_hash[:pet_name] = n.pet_name
   end
   A_proper_list << A_proper_hash
 }
```

I have no clue how to check this variable without crashing when all the checks I know crash it if it's not there?

Edit: An example of an "p n.inspect" is here:

```
#<User id: 55, middle_name: \"duke\">"
```

Comment: So, what exactly is `GroupOfPeople`?

Comment: @red_menace I wish I knew. It's some altered extension of another thing, ActiveRecord I beleive, heavily modified.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would provide (a) some sample data for `GroupOfPeople` and (b) your desired output. As it is, even if you get around the problem you describe, you will overwriting `A_proper_hash` in each iteration.

Comment: @Jvillian In my file, I'm outputting to list. I forgot to include that.

Comment: @jvillian Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a number of things amiss here...

`GroupOfPeople` is a non-conventional variable name in ruby. As is `Person`, `A_proper_hash` and `A_proper_list`. Check out [the style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) for more information. You should use variables like `group_of_people`, `person`, `a_proper_hash` and `a_proper_list`.

You have a typo in a number of places where you use `A__proper_hash` instead of `A_proper_hash`.

`GroupOfPeople.persons do` should be something like:

```
group_of_people.persons.each do |person|
end
```

...so you don't have to do that `Person = GroupOfPeople.persons` assignment.

Use `do..end` instead of curly braces (`{}`) for multi-line blocks as stated in [Single-line Blocks](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#single-line-blocks) in the style guide.

If you want to return an `array`, you can do:

```
group_of_people.persons.map do |person|
end
```

And then you can do something like:

```
group_of_people.persons.map do |person|
  %i(
    id
    middle_name
    pet_name
  ).each_with_object({}) do |attr_sym, new_person|
    new_person[attr_sym] = person.try(attr_sym)
  end
end
```

...which will give you:

```
[
  {:id=>1, :middle_name=>"Foo", :pet_name=>"Fluffy"}, 
  {:id=>2, :middle_name=>"Bar", :pet_name=>nil}, 
  {:id=>3, :middle_name=>nil, :pet_name=>"Bunny"}
]
```

If you don't want those nil values, then:

```
group_of_people.persons.map do |person|
  %i(
    id
    middle_name
    pet_name
  ).each_with_object({}) do |attr_sym, new_person|
    new_person[attr_sym] = person.try(attr_sym) if person.try(attr_sym)
  end
end
```

...which will give you:

```
[
  {:id=>1, :middle_name=>"Foo", :pet_name=>"Fluffy"}, 
  {:id=>2, :middle_name=>"Bar"}, 
  {:id=>3, :pet_name=>"Bunny"}
]
```

Comment: Shows promise, but it breaks at new_person[attr_sym] = person.try(attr_sym) saying "NameError"?

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_person'

Comment: Did you do `new_person = {}`? Do you have any typos?

Comment: Ah, I missed that line. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm still fairly new at Ruby, what *is* %i( variables)  if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: `%i()` turns whatever is inside of `()` into an array of symbols. So, `%i(foo bar)` yields `[:foo, :bar]`. You could just as easily use the array `[:foo, :bar]`. I just got in the habit of using `%i()`. BTW, `%w()` yields an array of strings. So, `%w(foo bar)` yields `["foo", "bar"]`.